Top Questions page - 'Staging Ground' questions
When reloading Stack Overflow on my mobile, the newly Staging Ground questions were added to the Top Questions page.
From the 7 visible questions, 5 are from the Staging Ground, that's more than 70%.
I'm aware this is different on a desktop view, around 4/5 out of 9 (~50% - or sometimes 91%), but:
I think the amount of Staging Ground questions should be reduced, if not removed all together.
Questions still in the staging ground are not per se interesting as the tab suggest. And since there already is a 'Staging Ground Home page' where you can find all the questions, they don't seem to belong between the interesting questions.
An option to disable (or reduce) the amount of Staging Ground questions would be even better.
Note; @Dan1st pointed out that this option already exists in your preferences panel.



FWIW, i display 50 at a time, and all the SG posts are bunched up at the top. It's far less than 70% with 50 per page, so i'm guessing they're artificially inserting them into the result set within the first 10

Seems like they do @KevinB, ofc it's different every time, but things like this beauty happens way to often :)

How do I filter out these staging ground questions?

You could use the search with staging-ground:0 instead of the start/top questions page.

That a nice option @dan1st, unfortunately it's not quite the same as the Top questions page. When using that option I can only choose between relevance, newest, active and score, not 'interesting'. Also the UX on that page misses a lot.

I know it's not the same but it's at least something that can be used. Also, you can disable showing Staging Ground posts in your preferences.

Went to [status-completed] but on second thought, leaving it in [status-review] for the moment. We've made a couple tweaks that significantly reduced the volume of Staging Ground questions that appear on the front page, and limits on the number of questions coming into Staging Ground also kicked in a few hours after it opened. Both these factors mitigated this problem. But I don't want to move it to [status-completed] until we're a little more sure we've done everything we want to here.

Yes! A way to hide those staging ground questions does exist! I was about ready to post a meta question asking for that feature since I couldn't find any way to or mention of it in the help

We deployed an update to this logic that would also address this issue on mobile devices. Previously, the logic was to randomly insert Staging Ground questions in the list which does not guarantee that they would be properly interspersed.
With this new update, there will still be a max of five Staging Ground questions but they always in fixed positions within the feed. We've done testing on mobile devices and within the list of visible questions, depending on which device you use, by default on page load there should be no more than two visible Staging Ground questions.
